# Magento Enterprise NO_CACHE cookie

Tags: caching, magento, magento-1.4

I'm using Magento Enterprise 1.8 and all cache options are enabled including page cache.

I created a basic module with basic functionality;

my controller looks like this in a nutshell

```
class MyModule_Customizer_DraftController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action 
{
     public function viewAction(){
          //random functionality to display layout, title, meta tags
     }
}
```

my block looks like this in a nutshell

```
class MyModule_Customizer_Block_Draft extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
{
     public function getItems()
     {
          //random functionality 
          return $items;
     }
}
```

every time I access the page it creates a NO_CACHE cookie with value 1, so when I access another page afterward like category landing page or product view page it become no longer cached. How to prevent NO_CACHE cookie from being created?

let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the block named `external.pagecache.cookie` from the layout.

There are several ways to achieve this.

I'd recommend to setup a custom layout file for your module and remove the block in the proper handle:

```
<layout>
    <customizer_draft_view>
        <remove name="external.pagecache.cookie" />
    </customizer_draft_view>
</layout>
```

You also can remove the cookie block *completely* by extending the `<default>` layout handle in one of your layout .xml files:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <remove name="external.pagecache.cookie" />
    </default>
</layout>
```

Be aware, that this will also remove the block for the `<catalog_product_view>` layout handle, which is probably not, what you want. See `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/pagecache.xml`:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="external.pagecache.cookie" template="pagecache/cookie.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Comment: those recommended solutions works on Magento Enterprise 1.9 and 1.10 but not 1.8. However Magento EE 1.8 has something similar but I removed it from my theme/layout before I asked this question and nothing changed. It still generating NO_CACHE cookie.